# Performance Test Power BI web portal to measure the reports retrieval performance with multiple users

Tags: jmeter, powerbi, performance-testing, neoload

My requirement is to measure the reports retrieval performance with multiple users on PowerBI portal.
So far I have been using JMeter and Neoload for capturing the requests which is very complicated as some requests are not captured properly and tou much of script enhancements like correlation.

Was wondering if Power BI Dedicated Capacity Load Assessment Tool serves my purpose. This is a powershell script and will it generate multiple users(around 25) simultaneously to retrieve the reports? or is limited by system capacity as we run it locally.

If not this,please suggest the way to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> .... as some requests are not captured properly and tou much of script
> enhancements like correlation. ....

Tell us about your training in load and performance testing.   If you are asked to perform tests in this space by your management, then they also owe you training and a mentor for a period of time.

As you have found in the use of the tools, their use is non-trivial.  There are particular foundation skills that need to be in place even before training and mentoring can begin.  Has your manager assessed your foundation skills?

PowerBi portal (if you are referring to app.powerbi.com) is a multi-tenant SaaS application residing in the cloud as a part of O365.   You should read very carefully your end user agreement for such an application.  Traditionally multi tenant SaaS applications will only commit to an uptime SLA, not a response time SLA.   So, you can test, but if you find that it is "too slow" for your organization, what then is your mitigation path to make it faster if your application provider has no contractural speed commitments?

You also have the issue of a test itself.  As you will be conducting a test against someone else's infrastructure, you need to have written permission from the folks that own, manage, and control the infrastructure that is your target at Microsoft.  Why, you may ask?  Well, as this is a multi-tenant application and you are pointing at their servers with the software equivalent of a tactical nuclear device and pulling the trigger, you have every possibility of impacting their committed uptime SLA with other parties.

The less training and mentoring you have had the possibility of a poorly constructed and implemented test rises and so does the possibility you will inadvertently take out systems in production.  A good example of this is your use of the term "simultaneous..."  Humans are chaotic instruments.  To have simultaneous events requires a clock tick and automation be involved.  Even when Kanye West releases a new limited article of clothing for sale, 300,000 people don't arrive in the same second, but instead over a 4-5 minute window.   Even on the largest credit card sales days, true simultaneity, defined as in the same critical section of code at the same time executing the same functions, is fewer than ten threads on a mainframe - think of all of the human chaotic events that have to be coincident worldwide for that to happen.

You need a mentor to help guide you through the logistics of testing an application hosted and managed by a third party while being in compliance with their license agreement.  You likely need training as well to be effective at the delivery of value.